# Testing if a string is different than any other in a set

Tags: java, string, set

I have a set of strings. I am trying to see if there are any outliers in the set. For example, assuming the set contains the following:

`Jade Jone
Jone Bone
Dade Bone
Tigger Trap`

I am trying to identify Tigger Trap since it does not contain any word in common with the other strings in the set.

Comment: And what is your question? If it is "how to do it" it is off-topic here. You have to ask specific question about programming. Try to solve this problem yourself and ask question if you have specific problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question presents as though you want someone to write the code for you. Can you explain what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: Maybe generate some kind of `Map` based on tokens

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general approach you could try:

1. Find the number of times each word appears
2. Find all set that only consist of words that appear once

The first of these likely involves creating a map from string to integers.